# Compare columns on two tables, and update table1 if it's column matches a column in table2

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so I have two tables. Both are full of emails. I need to update a column to "true" or "false" depending on if the email address appears in the other table. Currently my plan is to write a function in PHP to check every row, but it's extremely slow (loop within a loop checking a table with 250 000 rows against a table with 130 000 rows, which means 32 500 000 000 queries).

Is there a simpler or quicker way to do this in sql? I've been searching around but not finding much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to update `table1` and set the column to TRUE if the email was not found in the other table and FALSE if it exists, you can use a LEFT JOIN

```
update table1
left join table2 on table1.email = table2.email
set table1.bool_col = case when table2.email is null 
                           then 'true'
                           else 'false'
                      end
```

This willl update all records at once. Then you can do the same for the other table. Just switch the table names.

Comment: Thanks, that looks much simpler than the function I was going to use. That said, the email column is not unique. Will that matter?

Comment: No, it does not matter. If the join could be made you can set the column value.

Comment: Good to know. I was finally able to test it with the right data and it worked great. Much, much quicker than my original method would have taken. Much appreciated!